# Proper way to close a socket to avoid "connection reset by peer"

Tags: sockets

I have a client/server app that maintains a socket continuously.  When the client signs off, it sends a 'signing off' message to the server and then closes the socket and cleans up.  The server cleans up and closes the socket when it receives this message - and does not reply to the message.

On a fairly regular basis, I see "connection reset by peer" errors getting logged by the server without any complaints from end users, and I figure this must be an occasional timing issue in my sign-off sequence.  I do see the same errors when end users complain about their connections actually being dropped, so I'm wondering how to tell the difference between those scenarios - or even better, how to prevent the bogus 'connection reset' scenario in the normal case.

I'm guessing that in some cases the server's getting hit by the closed socket before (or during) receipt of the "signing off" message.  Is this possible?  Is there a proper sequence you're supposed to follow for letting a server know that the client is about to terminate before actually closing the socket?  Some way to check that the last message was delivered prior to closing?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 3):

The [`shutdown(s, SHUT_RDWR)`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/2/shutdown/) function should solve your problem.  There's a more complete explanation in [this document](http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/TCPRST.pdf).

Comment: Interesting, but not sure it's the same case.  The doc shows the client getting an error calling recv() after the server closes the socket.  I'm getting the "connection reset" error on the server, not the client.  The client calls send() and then close(), and the server sometimes gets a 'connection reset' error.  My server (on AIX) processes multiple sockets with the poll() function, and the connection reset error comes in response to poll().  If the client's 'signoff' message had been received first, the server would've read it, closed the socket and removed it from the list passed to poll().

Comment: One possibility, though.  My server sends out occasional 'keepalive' application messages (not TCP keepalives) after every 2 minutes or so of inactivity.  I suppose there could be a timing window where the client tries to signoff (send/close) without reading a keepalive that was already in transit.  Could that result in the server getting a connection reset error?

Comment: It's been a long time and I don't recall exactly how `poll()` compares with `select()`, but what I'm thinking is that the client `close()`s without a `shutdown()`, so `poll()` checks the socket (marked open on its side) for input and is surprised that the connection is reset. The keepalive _might_ be related, but shouldn't be, because it would just be a packet to read prior to closing, as far as I can remember.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that you have either written to a connection that had already been closed by the peer, or closed a connection without reading all the pending incoming data. In other words, an application protocol error.